# Uploaad image button in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created one google-form in that google-form i want user to upload their image. so i need a upload button to put their passport size image. i have written an separate code to upload image. where i can upload image the image comes and saved in drive. there are 2 pieces. i want this to merge or combine . i want to include a upload button image in the form and the uploaded image should come and save in the form spreadsheet. thanku

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //Display a confirmation message
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to merge this function to a Google form.

Comment: The only one would be to scrap the forms service entirely and build everything you want into the UIApp.